# PowerShell don't copy "MemberOf" based on CSV exclusions list

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv that contains security groups that should never be copied when creating or modifying user accounts within Active Directory. It looks like this:

```
securityGroup
"CN=Security Group 1,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com", "CN=Security Group 2,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com", "CN=Security Group 3,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com", "CN=Security Group 4,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

When copying AD groups, we use the following method:

```
$userName = [User which security groups are copied TO]
$modelUser = [User which security groups are copied FROM]
$modelMember = Get-ADUser $modelUser -Properties MemberOf
$modelMember.MemberOf | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $userName
```

What we would like to see is that no groups from the above CSV file are copied from a model user to another user. I have had some success by manually entering Security Groups over and over again using "-and" and "-not contains" in the script but would prefer to use a CSV instead.

```
$modelMember.MemberOf | Where{$_ -notcontains "CN=Security Group 1,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com" -and $_ -notcontains "CN=Security Group 2,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com" -and $_ -notcontains "CN=Security Group 3,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com" -and $_ -notcontains "CN=Security Group 4,OU=Security Groups,DC=domain,DC=com"} | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $userName
```

I guess I don't even know where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you show does not look like a CSV, those are groups one-per-line rather than comma-separated.

It's easy enough as long as you have PowerShell v3 or above:

```
$modelMember = Get-ADUser $modelUser -Properties memberOf

$forbiddenGroups = Get-Content groupList.txt
$modelGroups = $modelMember.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -notin $forbiddenGroups } 

$modelGroups | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $userName
```

---

**Auto-generated PS help links from my codeblock** (if available):

- [`Get-ADUser`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301397) (in module `ActiveDirectory`)
- [`Get-Content`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) (in module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`)
- [`Where-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423)
- [`Add-ADGroupMember`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219287) (in module `ActiveDirectory`)

Comment: good point about the CSV. I did not format that properly in the question and will fix that. Do you happen to know if Get-Content will work for CSV just like it will with .TXT?

Comment: @jdubs If you genuinely have a CSV, Get-Content will read the contents but the script logic won't make sense. You'll need to use `Import-CSV` and appropriate code to handle CSV header row (if you have one or not), and code to get the column your groups are in. But if you just use `Import-CSV` on the content you showed, it will break the group distinguished names apart at the commas thinking it's 4 columns, and that will just mess everything up.

Comment: $report = Import-CSV \\path\to\report.csv

Comment: $report = Import-CSV \\path\to\report.csv

$modelMember = Get-ADUser $modelUser -Properties memberOf

$modelGroups = $modelMember.MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -notin $report.SecurityGroups } 

$modelGroups | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $userName

Worked flawless for me. I think the key was the use of "-notin" as you suggested. The CSV automatically formatted to include quotes around the security groups so there was no issue there.